# Stack and base pointers

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

Hi i want to ask how the EBP and ESP registers are initialized and updated during program execution.

I have an image below and the author explains that when entering a new function, first the arguments are pushed onto the stack shown in the yellow region, then the base pointer EBP is updated and the base pointer of the previous function stored, followed by stack allocating more resources for local variables and return addresses.

I want to know wouldn't it be easier to simply update the base pointer when entering the new function, then allocate memory for the previous function's base pointer register address, followed by the arguments, local variables and return value? Instead of having the EBP in the middle of a stack frame for a function.

My other question is, where exactly does the return address value point to in the previous function, is it at the end of the previous function, or the start of the previous function?

My other question is, what significance does storing the previous function base pointer register if you already store the return address of the previous function?

The idea i get from pointers is that you essentially just want to use them as a reference for accessing resources local to a function, you can do with the return address

Thanks

[image: stack illustration]

Comment: This should get you started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: More reading - _"...The great thing about calling conventions on the x86 platform is that there are so many to choose from!..."_ - [Old New Thing - The history of calling conventions, part 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040102-00/?p=41213)  (5 parts in total)

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to the C++ language.

Comment: Thanks ill take a look

Answer (score 1):

To return from a function you need to restore (at least) two things.

One is where the *instruction pointer* is, what the next instruction you are running it located at.

The other is where the *stack pointer* is, where the data you are operating is.

(Depending on calling convention, registers may also have to be reset, but I don't know details here).

The return address -- the instruction pointer -- points to where the code should continue executing when returned from the call.  This isn't usually either the start or end of the calling function, but rather the "next instruction" after the call.  (But not really; it points to the code that handles the return from the function, which in some calling conventions does real work).

The code *calling* a function has to update the stack pointer so that the called function knows where its on-stack arguments are, and provide enough information for the called function to return.

The function *called* has no need to do that internally.  It (well, the compiler writing it knows) what variables it has put on the stack, and how big they are.  The set of variables on the stack may vary over time during the body of the function.  So updating the stack pointer is pointless, and would even make offset calculations a bit more complex (as they keep on changing, instead of being constant for a given "variable") and confusing for an assembly writer.

Code that accesses the stack does so with an offset regardless.  Not changing the stack pointer is doing less work than changing the stack pointer, and doing less work usually is faster than doing more work.

So you leave the stack pointer alone, unless you need to change it.

The return address is useless for accessing mutable data.  The return address points at usually read-only machine code, not at mutable state on the stack.

Now, there are plenty of calling conventions in the wild.  Many of them do slightly different things.  Which arguments go on the stack, which are stored in registers, what kind of arguments go where, and who resets the stack pointer (the caller or the callee) can vary, among other things.